# Dymo barcode label printing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dymo

We have an mvc app that prints labels that includes a barcode.  This uses the XML file to form the barcode:

```
<ObjectInfo>\
    <BarcodeObject>\
        <Name>BARCODE</Name>\
        <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
        <BackColor Alpha="0" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255" />\
        <LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName>\
        <Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation>\
        <IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored>\
        <IsVariable>True</IsVariable>\
        <Text></Text>\
        <Type>Code128Auto</Type>\
        <Size>Medium</Size>\
        <TextPosition>Bottom</TextPosition>\
        <TextFont Family="Arial" Size="12" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
        <CheckSumFont Family="Arial" Size="12" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
        <TextEmbedding>None</TextEmbedding>\
        <ECLevel>0</ECLevel>\
        <HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment>\
        <QuietZonesPadding Left="0" Top="0" Right="0" Bottom="0" />\
    </BarcodeObject>\
    <Bounds X="331" Y="178" Width="4260" Height="420" />\
</ObjectInfo>\
```

There is a code 39 with checksum.  How do I set the Type to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Type>Code39</Type>`
or
`<Type>Code39CS</Type>`

Tip: Run the DYMO software (DYMO Label v.8) and create a label just how you want it and then save it. You can open the label file in a text editor to see the XML.